# I get Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sh

When I run the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
folder="~/Desktop/"
if [ -d "$folder" ]; 
    then
    cd $folder;
    listofpdf=$( find *.pdf -type f);
    fi
echo ${listofpdf};

for words in $listofpdf
do
array+=("$words")
done
```

I get "Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")". It seems to be related to the array variable. Appreciate corrections . Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are running the script with `sh scriptname`, the shebang is ignored.

Comment: Yes, `dash` is used to interpret the script, thus the syntax error. By the way, the shell doesn't need all these semicolons at the end of line, they are only required to separate statements in the same line.

Comment: Also, `folder="~/Desktop"` doesn't work in bash, as double quotes prevent tilde expansion, and in `cd $folder`, tilde expansion happens before variable expansion, so the tilde isn't expanded.

Comment: I did remove `~`, shebang and the semicolons and did as you suggested. But the same result

Comment: http://shellcheck.net please and Good luck.

Comment: I tried http://shellcheck.net and I applied all its suggestions(globbing and double quotes) and the shellcheck terminal now says "no issues detected!". Yet, on my terminal,its the same error again. Btw  thank you @shellter for that website. It will save me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: The problem is solved. I was running the script with `sh scriptname`.I executed the script directly after `chmod +x filename` and it worked. Would appreciate an explanation.Thank you

Comment: You got an explanation in *the very first comment*, and the second one as well.

Answer (score 3):

Although your script is a valid `bash` script, it is not a valid POSIX shell script: arrays are not supported. Even if `sh` is a link to or copy of `bash`, it runs in a strict POSIX mode. In order to run a script with `bash` extensions, it *must* be run with `bash`, either by running `bash script` or (as you did) using `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang and executing the script directly with `./script`